# Induction Proof for Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

Given a sequence $s_k=s_{k-1}+6k$, where $s_0=7$.

Question: First, find the closed formula for the $n$-th component of this sequence by hand and then prove that your formula is correct

My attempt:
I found the first couple of terms of the sequence to be
$s_0=7$, 
$s_1=13$,
$s_2=25$,
$s_3=43$,
$s_4=67$ and 
$s_5=97$.

I found the formula for the $n$-th term to be $s_n=3n^2+3n+7$.

Proof:
Base case $s_0=7$ therefore
$7=3\cdot(0)^2+3\cdot(0)+7$ so the formula works for the $s_0$ element.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here but I believe the proof should be a proof by Strong Induction. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that induction is not needed here. Fix $k\in\Bbb N.$ A direct computation shows that $s_k-s_{k-1}=6k$ and $s_0=7.$ However, there is another problem: both induction, and my method show that **if** $s_k=3k^2+3k+7$, **then** $s_{k}=s_{k-1}+6k$. In fact, whe should prove the converse: **if** $s_{k}=s_{k-1}+6k$ and $s_0=7$, **then** $s_k=3k^2+3k+7$. I will look for some reasoning going in this direction.

Let $s_0=7$ and $s_{k}=s_{k-1}+6k.$ Define $t_k=s_k-3k^2-3k-7.$ Then $t_0=0$. It is easy to prove (by direct computation) that $t_k=t_{k-1}$, so $(t_k)$ is a constant (in fact, zero) sequence. Then $s_k=3k^2+3k+7.$

Comment: My answer has one way to show what you're asking about, i.e., "**if** $s_{k}=s_{k-1}+6k$ and $s_0=7$, **then** $a_k=3k^2+3k+7$".

Comment: Yes, of course. About such techniques one could read in the "Concrete mathematics" book by Graham, Knuth, Patashnik.

Answer (score 2):

You just apply the recurrence
to your induction hypothesis.

If
$s_n=3n^2+3n+7
$,
then,
since
$s_k=s_{k-1}+6k
$,

$\begin{array}\\
s_{n+1}
&=s_n+6(n+1)\\
&=3n^2+3n+7+6(n+1)\\
&=3n^2+9n+13\\
\end{array}
$

If your hypothesis is true,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s_{n+1}
&=3(n+1)^2+3(n+1)+7\\
&=3(n^2+2n+1)+3(n+1)+7\\
&=3n^2+6n+3+3n+3+7\\
&=3n^2+9n+13\\
\end{array}
$

This matches the result
from the induction step,
so the induction hypothesis is proved.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, here is a way to determine what the closed formula is without having to determine it by hand. This is an extension of the answer given by [szw1710](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/130298/szw1710). The given sequence is

$$s_k=s_{k-1}+6k \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Summing both sides of \eqref{eq1} from $1$ to $n$ gives that

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n}s_{k-1} + \sum_{k=1}^{n}6k$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_k + s_n = s_0 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}s_{k} + 6\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

$s_n = 7 + 3n(n+1) = 3n^2 + 3n + 7$

As you can see, this technique can easily be used in any cases where you have $s_k = s_{k-1} + f(k)$ and the sum of $f(k)$ up to $k = n$ can be fairly easily determined.

More generally, your question is a fairly simple example of [Linear Recurrence Relations with Constant Coefficients](https://www.javatpoint.com/linear-recurrence-relations-with-constant-coefficients). You can use a certain technique of a characteristic equation, as described in that link, to directly determine the solution of even considerably more complicated such equations.